# How to get zero values in list comprehension Python

Tags: python, list

I would like every element in `ll` to be `0` where the corresponding element in `frac` is `0`. So the first value of `ll` should be `0` and the rest unchanged. Thank you.

```
frac = [0,.1,.5,.3,.7,1.1]
ll = [[i + 1 for i in range(5) if i <= k*4 < (i+1)] for k in frac]
[[1], [1], [3], [2], [3], [5]]
```

Comment: something like this? `ll = [[i + 1 for i in range(5) if i <= k*4 < (i+1)] if k!=0 else 0 for k in frac]`

Comment: @FlorentMonin Has your answer, but I encourage you to use comprehensions when they make your code easier to follow not harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking something like this?

```
frac = [0,.1,.5,.3,.7,1.1]
ll = [[i + 1 for i in range(5) if i <= k*4 < (i+1)] for k in frac]
#[[1], [1], [3], [2], [3], [5]]

[x if y!=0 else 0 for x,y in zip(ll,frac)]  #zip both of them
#[0, [1], [3], [2], [3], [5]]
```

Or

```
[x if y!=0 else [0] for x,y in zip(ll,frac)]

[[0], [1], [3], [2], [3], [5]]
```

Or in one line as commented by @Florent

```
[[x + 1 for x in range(5) if x <= k*4 < (x+1)] if k!=0 else 0 for k in frac]

#[0, [1], [3], [2], [3], [5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly
by Using the `range` function and checking if the corresponding element in `frac` is zero using `if frac[i] == 0`. If it is, we set the first element of the `it` sublist of `ll` to 0 using `ll[i][0] = 0`. If the ith element of frac is NOT zero, the `it` sublist of `ll` remains unchanged.

Then the code would look something like this:

```
frac = [0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.1]
ll = [[i + 1 for i in range(5) if i <= k*4 < (i+1)] for k in frac]

# Set elements in ll to 0 where the corresponding element in frac is 0
for i in range(len(frac)):
    if frac[i] == 0:
        ll[i][0] = 0

print(ll)
```

Output should be

```
[[0], [1], [3], [2], [3], [5]]
```